# Textarea expand its width while the user is typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to make a textarea expand its width while the user is typing? Basically I'm using a border for the textarea therefore I need the WIDTH of the textarea to be only to the length of the longest line. So it looks nice and tidy.

Note: I'm allowing the user to change the font size of the textarea.

This is what I have but does not do what is required.

```
$(document).on("click blur keyup", ".fT", function() {
      var newWidth = ($('#tfd').val().length)*10;
      $('#tfd').width(newWidth);
});
```

I'm not concerned about the HEIGHT of the the textarea. I only need to fit the textarea to the text inside.

Comment: I'm missing something this works. http://jsfiddle.net/xp780m7h/1/

Comment: @dowomenfart: thanks... but you see the extra white space at the end?? I want the textarea to be only to the size of its text.

Comment: Why not set it to max allowed width right from the start? Or expand it to that full width on focus

Comment: @charlietfl" thanks, but what if the user adds a short sentence? then the textarea will not fit to its text. I want the textarea to be only to the size of its text.

Comment: You should probably have a min-width. Then you can have it scaling according to font size and text length. The fiddle provided by @dowomenfart seems to be working, at least the width expands while user types.

Comment: good luck then, will need to copy text to another inline element like offscreen span to find out what width is

Comment: @Mazvél: seems like a good suggestion. I'll try. I'm open to any another suggestions too...

Comment: @charlietfl: That makes sense... I'll try. open to any other suggestions...

Comment: @Mazvél: that did not work when the ENTER key is pressed (textarea keeps on expanding).

Comment: _“that did not work when the ENTER key is pressed”_ – of course you would have to _format_ your “other element” in a way that enter has the effect of a line break in the first place (`white-space` property), which in “normal” HTML outside of a textarea it doesn’t by default.

Comment: @CBroe: thanks what are you referring by "other element"?

Comment: I thought you were referring to the use another element to measure the width of the content as suggested by charlietfl and in Roman’s answer (where you commented the same).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly You want to achieve something similar to this:(jsfiddle deleted, see fiddle below)

It uses hidden div to calculate the width of the textarea based on the text content. The textarea has padding:0 so the width is strictly linked to it's content as You wanted. The div styles "min-width" and "max-width" defines the minimum and maximum width that textarea can collapse/expand to.

EDIT: The problem You pointed occurs due to the line wrapping in div. To avoid it You can eventually use CSS white-space: pre-line; propoerty. I updated (attached) example fiddle.

```js
$("#t1").on("keyup", function() {

  $("#d1").text($(this).val());
  $(this).css("width", $("#d1").css("width"));
  $(this).css("height", $("#d1").css("height"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="t1" style='min-width:100px;min-height: 100px; padding:0; font-size:14px'>

</textarea>

<div id="d1" style='max-width:200px;min-height:20px;white-space: pre-line; float:right;font-size:15px; display:none'>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's close but same issue as abuani's answer when the ENTER key is pressed...

Comment: JSFiddle examples are welcome. But please post the code also in your answer to make it more self contained. The links may break over time.

Comment: great suggestion. But still there are issues like the textarea adds line breaks even if the user doesn't hit the enter key. E.g.: if you type something like "Hey Diddle Diddle..." it shows in 2 lines rather than 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the biggest issue has to do with your selector. I have provided a JSBin illustrating what you're trying to achieve, however if you can create one with your exact scenario I can further help.

Your logic is correct, but the $(document).on("click blur keyup", ".fT") isn't being registered to the appropriate selector. Try changing that to:

`$(".fT").keypress(function() { // function handler here //; }`

Here's the current JSBin example to illustrate this:

http://jsbin.com/jogixotoca/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thanks. Looks good but there seems to be an issue if the user hits the enterkey. Then the textarea does not fit its text?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which is triggered while typing.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvc0L4ut/19/

```
<script>
    function expand(el, e){
        var text = el.value.split("\n");
        var minColSize = 19;
        for(var i=0; i < text.length; i++){
            minColSize = (text[i].length > minColSize) ? text[i].length : minColSize;
        }
        el.cols = minColSize + ((e.which == 8 && minColSize != 19) ? -1 : 1);
    }
</script>

<textarea onkeydown="expand(this, event)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

expanding the text area when user types is too easy.. use the following html

```
<textarea id="inbox" onclick="expand()" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;"></textarea>
```

And the following js script:

```
function expand(){
var box = document.getElementById('inbox');
box.style = "width: 500px; height: 500px;"
}
```

and if you think to exapand the textbox when someone types then use oninput =)